# PHP Session unset inside a function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm writing my own session handler and some of it is based off of CodeIgniters session handler. global_registered is set to off and this part of my class:

```
    protected $userdata = array();
    //in the initialization of the class after the session start i call
    $this->userdata =& $this->get_userdata();
    public function &get_userdata()
{
    // Just return reference to $_SESSION
    return $_SESSION;
}
    public function userdata($item)
{
    return isset($this->userdata[$item]) ? $this->userdata[$item] : NULL;
}
    public function unset_userdata($newdata = array())
{
    // Wrap single name as array
    if (is_string($newdata))
    {
        $newdata = array($newdata => '');
    }

    // Unset each item name
    if (count($newdata) > 0)
    {
        foreach (array_keys($newdata) as $key)
        {
            unset($this->userdata[$key]);
        }
    }

}
```

The unset is not working. I read a bit on php about unset and issues with functions but it wasn't clear to me on how to unset something within a funcation with globals off

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not allowed to comment:
Do you have session_start() some place else?

Comment: yes, this is just the relevant piece of code that I'm having an issue with. I call the class, it's starts the session, i can write data to it. read data from it, but i don't understand the unset global vs localized

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this issue was NOT php or codeigniter but the file system not truncating properly. Thanks:)